# Add inset shadow in fill Image Next13

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css, next.js13

I am trying to add inset shadow in my Image. But it is not working. The outer box shadow works fine.

`

```
<div className="relative  w-[500px] h-[500px] overflow-hidden group-hover:scale-[105%] transition-all duration-300 shadow-inner shadow-black">
    <Image src={imgSrc} alt="" fill style={{ objectFit: "cover" }} />
</div>
```

I have tried using following methods.

```
shadow-[inset_0_-10px_10px_-10px_#000000]
```